# Can I claim a draw if I am left with a king vs 2 knights?

Tags: rules, draw

I am in a tournament and I ended up with a king vs king + 2 knights. I know that the mate can not be forced in this situation, also if I will cooperate I can lose.

So can I claim a draw in this situation or should I just wait for my opponent to make 50 moves and only than claim a draw based on 50 move rule?

Comment: you can claim it, no need to wait the 50 move rule.